# How to change the color of a DataGridView-Cell containing a specific value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to change the color of a cell which has a specific value.
This is how I do:

```
using (GetPolicyErrors g = new GetPolicyErrors())
{
    g.GridView.DataSource = dts.Tables[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < dts.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dts.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            if (g.GridView.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value.ToString() == "1007175")
            {
                //g.GridView.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; // changes whole table color (works)
                //MessageBox.Show(g.GridView.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value.ToString()); // messagebox returns 1007175
                g.GridView.Rows[j].Cells[i].Style.BackColor = Color.Green; // does not work (compiles W/O error)
            }
        }
    }

    g.ShowDialog();
}
```

Can you please explain me why my code does not work? And can you provide me some other approaches for coloring a specific cell?

Comment: The reason why it do not work is because you are not handling it in Cell Formatting of grid. Manipulate cell back color in that event handler and it should work for you. You can check for the text in event handler as `e.Row.Cells[i].Text` and based on value you can manipulate formatting.

Comment: @praty Great answer, it works. It's already 2 days I've been trying to solve this problem. Thank you

Comment: Happy to help :). If it is ok with you I will add my comment in answers section for you to mark as answer.